# Reset (index) to 0 when changing tabs

Tags: javascript

I have a next and prev button in the content of a few tabs that run through steps, initially on the first active tab when you're on the page you can click through the steps and the Prev and Next button disables depending on whether you are on the first or last step

But when I click on a different tab with the same steps I want it to be completely reset the index to 0, currently when you click on another tab it breaks, prev and next buttons does not disable accordingly and I end up with "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of 'classList' of undefined

```js
      var currentStep = 0;
      showStep(currentStep);

      function showStep(index) {
        var steps = document.querySelectorAll(".tab-content.active .step");
        steps[index].classList.add('active-step');
        
        if (index == 0) {
          document.getElementById("previous").setAttribute('disabled',"disabled");
        } else {
          document.getElementById("previous").removeAttribute('disabled');
        }

        if (index == (steps.length - 1)) {
          document.getElementById("next").setAttribute('disabled',"disabled");
        } else {
          document.getElementById("next").removeAttribute('disabled');
        }
      }

      function nextPrev(index) {
        // This function will figure out which step to display
        var steps = document.querySelectorAll(".tab-content.active .step")
        steps[currentStep].classList.remove('active-step');

        // Increase or decrease the current step by 1:
        currentStep = currentStep + index;

        // if you have reached the end...
        if (currentStep >= steps.length) {
          return false;
        }

        // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
        showStep(currentStep);
      }

      // This is to add active class to selected tab with specific id and its content

      $('.tabs>div').on('click', function (index) {
        var tab = $(this).data('tab');
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

        $('#' + tab).addClass('active').siblings('.tab-content').removeClass('active');
      });
```

```css
    #steps .step {
      display: none;
    }

    .active-step {
      display: block !important;
    }

    #previous {
      font-size: 13px;
      font-weight: 500;
    }

    .tabs {
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .tabs>div.active {
      color: green;
    }

    .tabs>div {
      display: inline-block;
    }


    .tab-content {
      display: none;
    }

    .tab-content.active {
       display: block !important;
    }
```

```html
  
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="tabs">
        <div class="active" data-tab="tabOne">tabOne</div>
        <div data-tab="tabTwo">tabTwo</div>
    </div>

    <div id="tabOne" class="tab-content active">
        <div id="steps">
            <div class="step active-step">
              <h3>tabOne - Step 1</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="step">
              <h3>tabOne - Step 2</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="step">
              <h3>tabOne - Step 3</h3>
            </div>
           <div>
            <button id="next" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next step</button>
            <button id="previous" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Step back</button>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="tabTwo" class="tab-content">
        <div id="steps">
            <div class="step active-step">
              <h3>tabTwo - Step 1</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="step">
              <h3>tabTwo - Step 2</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="step">
              <h3>tabTwo - Step 3</h3>
            </div>
           <div>
            <button id="next" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next step</button>
            <button id="previous" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Step back</button>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's generally [not a good idea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) to use inline event handlers. Here's a mockup of your functions using event handlers from within the scripting (`addEventListener`) and [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation). To track the right 'tab' and the button elements for the handler, the snippet uses [`data-attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

Furthermore, the boundaries (first/last 'tab') are checked more thoroughly.

That said, I would not place the buttons on each tab. In [this mockup](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-answer-qxg8r) the buttons are placed at a fixed position within the page. Feel free to clone it.

```js
// add event listener
  document.addEventListener("click", navigateSteps);

  const activate = elem => elem.classList.add("active");
  const deactivate = elem => elem.classList.remove("active");
  const currentTab = () => document.querySelector("[data-nsteps].active");
  
  // activate first tab
  currentTab().click();

  function checkButtons() {
    // determine n of steps for this tab
    const nSteps = +currentTab().dataset.nsteps;
    // determine current step value for this tab
    const currentStep = +currentTab().querySelector(`[data-step]`).dataset.step;
    // enable all buttons initially
    document.querySelectorAll("[data-next]")
      .forEach(btn => btn.removeAttribute("disabled"));
    // check for the need to disable one of the buttons
    const prevNext = currentStep <= 1 ? "-1" : currentStep === nSteps ? "1" : "";
    if (prevNext) {
      document.querySelector(`button[data-next='${prevNext}']`)
        .setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
    }
  }

  function navigateSteps(evt) {
    const origin = evt.target;

    if (origin.dataset.tab || origin.dataset.next ) {

      if (origin.dataset.tab) {
        // tab clicked: activate it
        const newTab = document.querySelector(`[data-tab='${origin.dataset.tab}']`);
        const newContent = 
          document.querySelectorAll(`[data-nsteps]`)[+origin.dataset.tab-1];
        // remove all .active  
        document.querySelectorAll("[data-nsteps], [data-tab]").forEach(deactivate);
        // activate new tab and new content
        activate(newTab);
        activate(newContent);
        // reset step value for this tab content
        newContent.querySelector("[data-step]").dataset.step = 1;
      } else if (origin.dataset.next) {
        // button clicked
        const prevStep = +currentTab().querySelector(`[data-step]`).dataset.step;
        currentTab().querySelector(`[data-step]`).dataset.step = 
          prevStep + +origin.dataset.next;
      }

      checkButtons();
    }
  }
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 1rem;
}

[data-tab] {
  color: #c0c0c0;
  margin: 0.3rem;
  background-color: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
}

[data-tab]:before {
  content: 'Tab' attr(data-tab);
}

[data-tab].active,
[data-tab]:hover {
  color: red;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: white !important;
  box-shadow: -3px -3px 8px #eee;
}

ul.tab {
  margin-left: -2rem;
  margin-top: -0.5rem;
  position: absolute;
}

ul.tab li[data-tab] {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 3px 8px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #777;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  margin: initial 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

li.bttns {
  position: fixed;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}

li.bttns div {
  margin: 5px 0 0 1rem;
}

[data-nsteps] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2.4rem;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 3rem;
  padding: 1rem 2rem 0 2rem;
  display: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #999;
  z-index: -1;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

[data-nsteps].active {
  display: block;
}

[data-nsteps]:before {
  content: 'N Steps 'attr(data-nsteps);
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 0.8rem;
  width: 5em;
  color: green;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
}

[data-nsteps].active b:before {
  content: 'Currently @ step ' attr(data-step);
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tab">
  <li data-tab="1" class="active"></li>
  <li data-tab="2"></li>
  <li data-tab="3"></li>
  <li data-tab="4"></li>
  <li data-tab="5"></li>
  <li class="bttns">
    <div>
      <button id="next" data-next="1">Next step</button>
      <button id="previous" data-next="-1">Previous step</button>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<div data-nsteps="5" class="active">
  Tab 1, <b data-step="1"></b>
</div>
<div data-nsteps="3">
  Tab 2, <b data-step="1"></b>
</div>
<div data-nsteps="2">
  Tab 3, <b data-step="1"></b>
</div>
<div data-nsteps="4">
  Tab 4, <b data-step="1"></b>
</div>
<div data-nsteps="5">
  Tab 5, <b data-step="1"></b>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I'm still sitting with the initial problem, I want to apply these steps in multiple tabs (different tabs with different content showing once clicked), the problem is if I click next in the a different tab I selected the step and attributes on buttons only changes in the first tab

I want to reset everything when clicking on a new tab within its content

Comment: For that problem your question has too little information. Let's say I tried to present  some scaffolding code for the handling of the activation of html elements, but you have to do the actual building (using the right css to show/hide tabs/tab-content etc.). Furthermore the answer contains a few links that may be usefull for the handling part of the code itself.

Comment: Yea, I've updated my question to show html of the tabs and its content, but thank you, will be going through the links thoroughly now

Comment: [A more extended mockup](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-answer-qxg8r) may help.

Comment: Hi! I'm sorry, I'm still figuring out posting on here, I updated my initial question but still using my old code with a code snippet to show what I mean about the behaviour changing/not working when switching tabs

Comment: I see what you mean. Adjusted the code (enabled 'tab' click)

Comment: Yea, so the steps shouldnt be tabs, a set of 3 steps should display on clicking different tab from Step 1 with prev disable ect like on the first tab

Comment: Again @Nikki, I've offered you skeleton code here and in a [mockup @codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/embed/stackoverflow-answer-qxg8r?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) to work with, assuming the problem was the disabling of buttons on the step boundaries. You should figure out if 1) this is usable for what you need and if so 2) how to use it in your code.

Comment: I tried too manipulate your code, my js skills arent that strong but I dont believe it'll answer what I am trying to achieve, I'm not sure you completely understand that its not one pair of steps, please see my code snippet again, clicking through the tabs should not effect the steps or buttons, only when clicking next and prev and by doing this in the content of tabOne should not effect the steps in tabTwo

Comment: Final bid: check [this revision @ codesandbox.il](https://codesandbox.io/embed/stackoverflow-answer-qxg8r?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Or check the snippet from the answer

Comment: Thank you for the time you've put into helping me and responding, I looked at your snippet, and it work welland I see you said " I would not place the buttons on each tab." but that's what I need but if I clone them in each in each tabs content to run through the steps of that tab within that tab, that's where my problem pops up and what I need help with

Comment: Cloning the buttons in each tab needlessly complicates your code. Two buttons should be sufficient, study the code I provided. Escpecially the use of `data-attributes`: they help tracking the boundaries for the buttons.

Comment: Ah, yea so it seems, thank you again though, I appreciate it